# WP ACF Как получить значение key и value для выбранных checkbox?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Подскажите, как в Wordpress плагине [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/) (`ACF`) для выбраных значений в типе чекбоксов выводить все выбранные и поля и значения в цикле ? (Использую версию 5.9.6)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<li class="info_item">
  <div>Поддерживаемые страны:</div>
  <div>
    <?php
      $countries = get_field('supported_countries');
      if( $countries ): ?>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach( $countries as $country ): ?>
        <li>
          <?php echo $country['value']; ?> :
          <?php echo $country['label']; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
```

Мне на выходе почему-то отдает задублированые значения. Хотя предполагалось что-то по типу `it: Italya`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя вроде ж как : является символом разделителем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ такой:

```
<li class="info_item">
  <div>Поддерживаемые страны:</div>
  <div>
    <?php
      $countries = acf_get_field('supported_countries');
      if( $countries ): ?>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach( $countries['choices'] as $value => $label ): ?>
        <li>
          <?php echo $value; ?> :
          <?php echo $label; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
```

Единственный вопрос который ещё остался, это как работать с данным выводом в цикле, когда необходимо подставлять значения в зависимости от $id поста. Такой вариант
 `$countries = acf_get_field('supported_countries', $id);` не работает. Когда идет перебор постов то всем выводятся сразу все